Getting user input in a modal vs offcanvas
I need to show a form for user input, and can choose between a modal or offcanvas. (Those links are Bootstrap 5 examples, but the same would apply to any UI toolkit.)
Once there was no offcanvas, just modals/popups - but now many big companies use them heavily. For example, in many of Google professional tools they now use offcanvas instead of popups.
When is it generally better to use the one or the other, or, what are the tradeoffs involved?
(This is for a website generally used by business users on their desktops, but many will nonetheless use it in their mobile browsers too. I'd like some general tips though, not just for business-oriented sites.)

An off-canvas is much less irritating than a modal window. While this one cancels all types of navigation that are not from the window itself, the other allows you to continue interacting on the page.
Starting from this premise, of all the possible off-canvas options, the least "invasive" is the one placed at the bottom.

On The Guardian, all menu and submenu options are clickable despite the form that takes up practically 50% of the bottom of the page



Thanks, that's a good observation! There are offcanvas implementations though that behave the same as modals - they prevent interaction with the underlying page. I was thinking of doing that, but now I'll reconsider.
